# How can I force a nameserver resolution using the second nameserver on an ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, networking, domain-name-system, ubuntu-16.04

I try to download something from `nvidia` on a remote server via ssh. Iran is banned by the `nvidia` website. When I check the server `dns`, that is:

```
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.20.14
IP4.DNS[2]:                             8.8.8.8
```

I know if I could set the dns to google dns (8.8.4.4 or 8.8.8.8) then I was able to surf the website and download from it. I tried to change the dns on the server but whatever I do it's the same as above.

Its the content of `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
uto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#auto enth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 172.16.143.8
        netmask 255.255.255.224
        gateway 172.16.143.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

This is the output of `ifconfig`

```
eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 34:97:f6:dc:9f:ff  
          inet addr:172.16.143.8  Bcast:172.16.143.31  Mask:255.255.255.224
          inet6 addr: fe80::c8cd:597a:b384:a22b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2101 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1298 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:891719 (891.7 KB)  TX bytes:237702 (237.7 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:fb200000-fb220000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
```

I wonder why network id is `eno1`?! it's the output of `sudo nmcli c`

```
NAME                UUID                                  TYPE            DEVICE 
Wired connection 1  532cfa3a-d61b-4bc4-b516-1dc31a5baead  802-3-ethernet  eno1
```

Once I changed `eth0` to `eno1` but then I couldn't access the server until the file was set back to `eth0`

I also installed `resolvconf` and followed instruction of this website

https://www.tecmint.com/set-permanent-dns-nameservers-in-ubuntu-debian/

the content of `/etc/resolv.conf` is preserved but the dns doesn't change

Yet, I might be able to use the secondary dns to connect a website (using `wget` or other solutions)

Is it possible, what could I do?

Comment: How did you configure your networking?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I wrote more about my efforts.

Comment: Your interface name is `eno1`, not `eth0`. You can fix the `interfaces` file. But more is needed. Please post the output of `sudo nmcli c`.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I did in the question, also once I changed eth0 to eno1 but then I couldn't access the server until the file was set back to eth0

Comment: Well, that's very strange, but I guess it's harmless. You can just leave it as it is then.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your system is using NetworkManager to manage its connection to the network. This is helpful, because what you want to do needs to be done in NM, and cannot be done in the interfaces file.

You need to modify a NetworkManager setting for your connection to tell it to ignore the DNS servers provided by DHCP so that it will only use your chosen DNS servers:

```
nmcli c mod "Wired connection 1" ipv4.ignore-auto-dns true
```

You can then restart the network or the computer. All of your DNS queries should now use your chosen nameservers.

Comment: thanks, I was able to set the dns and its now `8.8.8.8`. When I did the same on my laptop I was able to connect NVIDIA website. However, on the server I still has the `403` error (forbidden). I forgot to say that on the server I must connect to an `ISP` that provides internet for users. Then maybe I have no control on their internet!? right?

Comment: I think Iran does not only use DNS to block some websites, but other techniques as well. Your best bet for accessing such sites is to use a VPN. Be sure that you do not use a VPN based on PPTP as these are not secure.

Comment: You mean to install VPN on the server? Yes, Iran blocks some websites, but our problems is that the US again blocks the rest. Many services of google, nividia, oracle, ... are banned for Iranians (by the US) and we should circumvent those too.

Comment: back to `wget`, here it speaks about `--bind-dns-address`, could it be a solution?, however my `wget` doesn't have such option (maybe not up to date), mine is 1.17 on ubuntu 16, and `apt` says its up to date! while it's for 2015

Comment: You should subscribe to a VPN service which is hosted outside of Iran, for example, in Turkey, or UAE, or somewhere in Europe. Then you can access sites in the USA using that VPN.